# Parse.com hosting rollback local version

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I've deployed something wrong to Parse.com and successfuly rolled back to the previous version with the help of the command

```
parse rollback -r v66
```

But this command does not synchronize my local files which I use for deployment with cloud files. Is it possible to rollback the local version too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we can't do that.

It is advisable to use Git/Svn/other system & mark every important *deploy* a commit point in the repo so we can revert in local also.

Comment: Okay. It seems to be very weird that Parse does not include this option.

Comment: Yes, but we can request on community that they allow to download the *zip* of the current version of Cloud Code deployed, like *Export Data*

Comment: This is the exact thing I was asking for... Anyway, this is quite good idea.